# How do I hash characters defined by user input?

Tags: python, input, hash

I've scrapped together a program that will hash a set of characters defined by:

```
hash_object = hashlib.sha256(b'Test')
```

I'd like to make the user input what is to be hashed instead of having to edit the program every time I want to hash something different than "Test".

This is how the program looks now, although the 2nd line is currently useless, but that is supposed to be where I input the string of characters to be hashed.

How do I make this program recognize 'x' as the hash_object?

The current program:

```
import hashlib
x = input("")
hash_object = hashlib.sha256(b'Test')
hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
print("Original hash     : ", hex_dig)
print("Every 9 characters: ", hex_dig[::5])

wait = input()
```

User Paul Evans asked wether or not I can use

```
hash_object = hashlib.sha256(x)
```

Which I cannot as it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\einar_000\Desktop\Python\Hash.py", line 3, in <module>
    hash_object = hashlib.sha256(x)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, am I missing something or is it just:

```
hash_object = hashlib.sha256(x)
```

Comment: Edited my post about this

Answer (score 0):

So the correct answer is somewhat similar to that which Paul Evans said, only you need to add

```
.encode()
```

So, the program now looks like this:

```
import hashlib
x = input("")
hash_object = hashlib.sha256(x.encode())
hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
print("Original hash     : ", hex_dig)
print("Every 9 characters: ", hex_dig[::5])

wait = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from hashlib import sha256

def generate_sha256(your_text: str) -> str:
    return sha256(your_text.encode()).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**